# Why .substring() does not work well in my java project?

Tags: java, string, file, csv

I'm trying to erase a row from a CSV file with this function:

```
public void borrarAlumno(String id) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivo));
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        //System.out.println(line.substring((5)));
        if(!" ".equals(line)  && line != null){
            if(!line.substring(0, 6).equals(id)){
                sb.append(line);
            }
        }
    }
    br.close();
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File(archivo));
    fw.write(sb.toString());
    fw.close();


}
```

But i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -5
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source
```

The first line of the file is: `Matricula,Nombre,Apellido`. Why am I getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: You have a bug here for sure: `line != " "` needs to become `!" ".equals(line)`.

Comment: Still get the same Exception @npinti

Comment: This does not answer your question concerning substring, but you could just use `!line.startsWith(id)` instead of `!line.substring(0, 6).equals(id)` to avoid a lot of problems when checking your condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is making the following call `line.substring(0, 6)` which is possible cause of an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if `line.length() < 6` as stated in the javadoc of [String#subString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)):

> **Throws:**
>   `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the `beginIndex` is negative, or `endIndex` is larger than the length of this String object, or `beginIndex` is larger than `endIndex`.

You could change your `if` statement as follows to avoid this problem:

```
if (line.length() >= 6 && !line.substring(0, 6).equals(id)) {
    sb.append(line);
}
```

**Unrelated:**

Since you are checking if `line != null` in the `while` condition it is completely unnecessary to check it again in the first `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails if the line is shorter than 6 characters. Java has a different method in `String` that is much more convenient when you want to check whether a string starts with some other string, since it works without checking the length first. That method is `String.startsWith`:

```
if (!line.startsWith(id)) {
    sb.append(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception must be coming from `System.out.println(line.substring((5)));` because when `String#substring(int)` validates the parameter, it subtracts it from the length of the string. If `line` has length of zero, it'll see that `0 - 5 < 0` and throw the exception. You could move that line to the inside of the following conditional block, but you'll need to debug further after that.

Answer (score 0):

IndexOfBounds thrown when the string is shorter than the start of substring. You should check the string length before substring :

```
if(line.length() > 5) System.out.println(line.substring((5)));
```